# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './DescriptionCard.scss' in 'D:\admin-predictive-analysis\admin-panel\src\ui-component\cards\Description'

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am using Scss or Sass for the first time. I am using Berry React Template.

In ui-component, I have a div that I want to have follow classname "my-class"  from SCSS file.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography,  Box} from '@mui/material';
// import "../Description/DescriptionCard.scss"
import './DescriptionCard.scss';

function DescriptionCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className='my-class'>
    <Typography variant="h4">Description</Typography>
    <Box>{props.description}</Box>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DescriptionCard;
```

The  Scss file is

$primary-color: #4CAF50;

.my-class {
background-color: $primary-color;

}

The div in my js is not getting the css even though I imported the ".SCSS" file.

**Note: My Scss is perfectly installed. It is following style.scss classes etc but does not work in separate scss files**